# jQuery javascript scoping problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have a hidden input element that I am using as a counter to use to name more input elements generated by JavaScript. To get the value of the counter i use

```
parseInt($('#counter').val());
```

However I use this code snippet several times in my code, so I thought it would be good to put it in a function

```
function getCounter(){
   parseInt($('#counter').val());
}
```

this always returns undefined, while running just the code snippet returns the correct value. This happens in several ways that I tried defeining the function, as a function inside a $(function(){}), as a global function etc. How do I fix the scoping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add "return" to your return statement :)

```
function getCounter(){
   return parseInt($('#counter').val());
}
```

Comment: Don't feel silly... it's always the little, assumed things that are impossible to catch. It just usually takes a fresh pair of eyes :)

Comment: Only thing that is wrong with the solution is it needs to have the base included. return parseInt($('#counter').val(), 10); so you do not run into the Octal problem.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the missing return too.  I was just getting ready to add a comment asking for more code, thinking it was really a scoping problem....

Comment: @Craig, you may want to look into CoffeeScript... It's Javascript for Ruby escapees :)

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a return

```
function getCounter(){
   return parseInt($('#counter').val());
}
```